# How to find updated rows between two pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

- I have one two source of data. One data is old and one is current version of same data.
- I need to find `new` and `updated` and `deleted` rows in this two data.
- Here is an example. `Updated` in a sense values of any column is changed from old data.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4],'b':[4,np.nan,6,12]})
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[2,1,3,5],'b':[np.nan,40,6,6]})
>>> df1
   id     b
0   1   4.0
1   2   NaN
2   3   6.0
3   4  12.0
>>> df2
   id    b
0   2  NaN
1   1  40.0
2   3  6.0
3   5  6.0
```

- here id is primary key for table.
- I can easily find new rows from comparing primary key.

```
>>> df2[~df2.id.isin(df1.id)]
   id    b
3   5  6.0
```

- But i am having trouble finding updated rows in new data source.
- I tried following

```
>>>tmp = df1.merge(df2)
>>> df2[(~df2.id.isin(tmp.id)) & (df2.id.isin(df1.id))]
   id     b
1   1  40.0
```

- This works for given case. But when i apply same thing to my original data frame -(shape `(97000,58)` and two columns combined makes a PK)- is not giving desired result. Its giving rows that are not updated.
- My question is 'Is this the right way to achieve this?'.
- How can i improve this?

Comment: What is the definition of "updated" that the value of `b` changed?

Comment: @DanielMesejo Yes Correct

Comment: So basically what you have to do for updates is to check which columns have change their value

Comment: @Daniel Mesejo. Yes correct. I can just iterate over new data and check if its updated or new data and append that index or PK in a list. But this looks non pythonic and i think it will take a lot of time given large dataset.

Comment: I appreciate people down voting question without commenting what's wrong with it. Thanks, for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the intersection of the ids and simply compare using `==`. This is only possible because you have identically-labeled data frames (i.e. same indexes - due to the intersection - and same columns).

```
ids = set(df1.id.unique()).intersection(df2.id)
```

```
d1 = df1[df1.id.isin(ids)].set_index('id').sort_index()
d2 = df2[df2.id.isin(ids)].set_index('id').sort_index()
```

```
comp = (d1 == d2) | (pd.isnull(d1) & pd.isnull(d2))
```

which gives a boolean data frame with `True` values wherever values are equal, and `False` values wherever they differ

```
   id      b
0   1  False
1   2   True
2   3   True
```

Comment: Let me try this. I will try this for my original data and see if it works or not.